# Admob below background

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbs7l.png

I'm trying to setup admob below the background, but I keep getting admob on top of the background like this . 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJXU2.png

So what happened is I have a button alignedParentBottom="true"
but the ad is keep covering the button.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:textSize="40sp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ></Button>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/backButton"        
     >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"

    android:text="@string/helphelp"></TextView>
</ScrollView>


<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView2"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY_UNIT_ID"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                     android:layout_below="@id/backButton"></com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Have you tried a FrameLayout?

Comment: No, how and where do I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second RelativeLayout - the inner one will have all of your main layout content, and the outer one will hold your layout content and the AdView.  Simply set the AdView to the bottom, and set your RelativeLayout content above the AdView, and it will force the back button up when the ad comes back.

I have provided the code here for your convenience.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView2">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </Button>
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/backButton">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/helphelp">
            </TextView>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adUnitId="MY_UNIT_ID"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true">
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Side note: Make sure your UI elements aren't too close to the ads; that may encourage accidental clicks, and is against AdMob's ToS.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html):

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.

There's nothing to it.  If you want to ensure that the Button is drawn over the AdView, then place the AdView earlier in a common FrameLayout parent.  E.g.,

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView2" ... />
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        ... Buttons, etc. ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Although you may want just the Button and AdView in a FrameLayout child of the RelativeLayout.  Or you may want a RelativeLayout parent of the AdView in the example above, to position the ad.